# C++ client update

Tags: c++, client-server, client

I am looking to add a client-version-check on a opensource client. I am new to coding but am researching as I work on "real projects" so this is more about the most efficient way of doing what I am trying to do. I am unable to find someone with a similar question, or I am just missing the keywords necessary to search for them.

What I want is; the client is assigned version number: 12, it checks with a server if 12 matches with a server value(can be as simple as sending the message 12 to any client that connects to the server). If it does it just opens up a message box client side stating that it is the correct version, a not correct version box if it doesn't match, and a cannot check message if it could not connect to the server.

If anyone can point me in the right direction of commands and other things I should look at that would be much appreciated. I apologize if my formatting is incorrect and if this question has been answered before.

Answer (score 0):

When any client connects to the server

1. The clients writes `write( int__fd, const void*__buf, size_t__nbytes)` (used for sending data to server)
2. the server reads `read( int__fd, const void*__buf, size_t__nbytes)`
3. Server already has a set of values. Compare the send value with the list. If `YES` write to server `version ok`

If you dont know how to `create socket`, `listen`, `bind` ... `etc` would gladly help

Answer (score 0):

The expected result is "correct version", and you should not bother the user with all things that are correct. That's the expectation anyway. Also, you already have existing code in the project to exchange messages with the server and show UI messages, so we can't really help you with that.

The algorithm of your version check is correct, though. Do remember to test how the client handles server upgrades (which may require some downtime, if only to disconnect old client versions)